# CoreData NSUndoManager issues with relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a managed object Employee with a many-to-one relationship to Department. So one Employee can be in a single Department, but Department can contain multiple employees.

I use undo manager to register the deletion of some Employee. After that *I turn off undo registration* I delete the Department. Department deletion deletes all remaining Employees since it has `Cascade Delete` rule set on it.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *defaultContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];        
NSUndoManager *undoManager = [defaultContext undoManager];

[undoManager enableUndoRegistration];
[undoManager setActionName:@"Delete"];

[employee MR_deleteEntityInContext:defaultContext];

// let undo manager finish registering events on current run loop
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate date]];
[undoManager disableUndoRegistration];

// ...

// somewhere later without undo manager enabled
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
   Department *department = [departmentOnMainThread MR_inContext:localContext];
   [department MR_deleteEntityInContext:localContext];
}];
```

Then I undo the deletion of Employee which resurrects together with Department on my context.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *defaultContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];        
NSUndoManager *undoManager = [defaultContext undoManager];

[undoManager enableUndoRegistration];
[undoManager undo];

[defaultContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

// let undo manager finish registering events on current run loop
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate date]];
[undoManager disableUndoRegistration];
```

The funny thing is, when I run undo, `[defaultContext deletedObjects]` of my context contains Department, Employee that I originally captured with `NSUndoManager` and some other Employee that probably got removed along with Department but that change wasn't actually captured during the deletion of original Employee. This other Employee has all fields set to nil.

Out of curiosity I called `[defaultContext refreshAllObjects]` which responded with:

> CoreData: warning: An NSManagedObjectContext delegate overrode fault
>   handling behavior to silently delete the object with ID
>   '0xd000000000280000
>   ' and
>   substitute nil/0 for all property values instead of throwing.

The question is, probably that other Employee should be really deleted, but how can I restore the original Employee and Department both of which apparently should be put back to database?

`NSUndoManager` restores them as deleted objects which does not make much sense.

Comment: Please clarify: 1. You have a 1:n relationship from `Department` instances to `Employee` instances, not the other way round. 2. The deletion of employees and the undo operation of this action is registered automatically or do you have explicit code for this? If so, post the code. 3. You first delete employees belonging to a department and then delete the department with still having employees? 4. You want to undo the first operation before undoing the second one?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad 1. as I said before one department many employees. 2. I register only first deletion of employee. Department removed from other controller which does not have undo registration enabled. 3. I first delete a single employee with undo manager registration enabled, then I delete the department "off-the-books", then I undo. 4. I want to undo the removed employee with department regardless that the whole department was later removed with all its employees. I want department to resurrect with a single employee in it.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra Xcode 7 GM but that probably doesn't matter.

Comment: 1. Okay, but you said the exact opposite in your first sentence. Maybe you want to correct that. 2. Please add the code for removing and undo registration. 4. It is not possible to und an operation that is not the last operation. It is an undo stack with push and pop, but no "indexed access".

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad 1. You are right, I fixed that so many-to-one relationship between Employee and Department.  2. Added some code 4. I know, the point is that some of ops go off-the-books without undo manager enabled.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad You deviate, it's easy, first I remove employee, undo manager knows that, then I delete whole department which deletes all employees, this is not registered in undo manager because well I don't want to register that. But next what happens is if I run undo the department and that single first removed employee put back on context however as deleted objects. This apparently results in no-op when saving the context.

Comment: Again: You cannot undo an action, that has a subsequent action. Undoing the forecast action is impossible in many cases and of course not supported. (I. e. undoing the deletion of the employees cannot bring back the department they belong to.) You have to register all actions or none, otherwise you fight the framework. It's is still a stack and it will be a stack when I write my next comment. Therefore obviously you cannot select operations for undoing and operations not for undoing. So register all actions and use undo groups.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad thanks that's what I thought but was not sure.

Comment: Come on man @AminNegm-Awad, post your answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by [Amin Negm-Awad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/676558/amin-negm-awad):

> You cannot undo an action, that has a subsequent action. Undoing the
>   forecast action is impossible in many cases and of course not
>   supported. (I. e. undoing the deletion of the employees cannot bring
>   back the department they belong to.) You have to register all actions
>   or none, otherwise you fight the framework. It's is still a stack and
>   it will be a stack when I write my next comment. Therefore obviously
>   you cannot select operations for undoing and operations not for
>   undoing. So register all actions and use undo groups.